# Admin only taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, admin

I'm building a marketplace site using woocommerce, wcvendors pro, buddyboss marketplace and buddypress.

I'd like for the admin to have an admin-only taxonomy that she can use to tag/categorise certain products for use in featured blocks on the home page, for example.

What would be the best approach for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When registering the taxonomy just set `public` to `false`, and it' won't be accessible on the front end. Just make sure to specify `show_ui` to `true`, otherwise it will use the public value and be hidden.

```
register_taxonomy(
    'my_taxonomy',
    'product',
    [
         'public'  => false,
         'show_ui' => true,
    ]
);
```

If you're registering the taxonomy with a GUI from a plugin it should have checkboxes for these options.